# Got an error integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, lstm

I have a dataset with three inputs and trying to predict next value of X1 with the combination of previous inputs values.

My three inputs are X1, X2, X3.

So here I am trying to predict next future value of X1. To predict the next X1 these three input combination affect with:

```
X1 + X2 - X3
```

So I wrote the code for using look_back method. Here output is one , so I used look_back=1.

x (dataX) is my inputs and y (dataY) is my output. 
Then I want to write that this output y is also equal to this algorithm `X1 + X2 - X3`

Then I tried this code it gave me this error. my data

```
date        time      X1    X2  X3
10/3/2018   6:00:00   63    0   0
10/3/2018   7:00:00   63    0   2
10/3/2018   8:00:00   104   11  0
10/3/2018   9:00:00   93    0   50
10/3/2018   10:00:00  177   0   2
10/3/2018   11:00:00  133   0   0
10/3/2018   12:00:00  70    0   0
```

when I wrote it  gave me an error:

> only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

How to solve this error:

```
def create_dataset(data, look_back=1):
dataX, dataY = [], []
for _ in range(len(data)-1):
    out=np.int(data['X1']+ data['X2'] - data['X3'])
    y=0
    while out >0:
        y = out
        if(y>out):
            dataX, dataY = dataY, dataX
for i in range(len(data) - look_back - 1):
    a = data[i:(i + look_back), :]
    dataX.append(a)
    dataY.append(data[i + look_back, 0])
return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)


data = data.values

# normalize the dataset
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
data = scaler.fit_transform(data)

# split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(data) * 0.67) 
test_size = len(data) - train_size
train, test = data[0:train_size, :], data[train_size:len(data), :]

look_back=3
x_train, y_train = create_dataset(train, look_back)
x_test , y_test = create_dataset(test, look_back)
```

When I run the code it gives so much error:

> 64  x_train, y_train = create_dataset(train, look_back)

[My csv file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hAf6RnHfUouUVLxR8Nqj-m5uSB1QOdqZ/edit#gid=1181284935)